# MySQL update based on GROUP BY result where column is MAX

Tags: mysql

Given the following table structure in a table `people`:

| id (int, PK) | name | group_id | net_worth (float) | is_leader (bool) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | 5000.0 | 1 |
| 2 | Mike | 1 | 8000.0 | 0 |
| 3 | Paul | 2 | 3000.0 | 0 |
| 4 | Logan | 2 | 5000 .0 | 0 |

I want to update `is_leader` so that each `group_id` has only **one** entry that has `is_leader` = `1` *(only 1 leader per group)*, the leader of a group is determined by whoever has the highest `net_worth` value.

The condition however is to not update a group if it already has a leader (determined by `is_leader` = `1`)

How can I fetch all members of groups **that don't already have leaders**, and from the resultset determine who will be the leader based on highest `net_worth`?

**My Attempt**

So far I am only able to fetch the person with the highest `net_worth` for each group, however it still fetches groups that already have a leader.

```sql
SELECT `id`, `name`, MAX(`net_worth`)
FROM `people`
WHERE `is_leader` = 0
GROUP BY `group_id`
ORDER BY `name` ASC;
```

**Expected Output**

| id (int, PK) | name | group_id | net_worth (float) | is_leader (bool) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | 5000.0 | 1 |
| 2 | Mike | 1 | 8000.0 | 0 |
| 3 | Paul | 2 | 3000.0 | 0 |
| 4 | Logan | 2 | 5000 .0 | 1 |

- Group `1` is not affected because it already has an appointed leader, even though another member has a higher `net_worth`.
- Group `2` was appointed a new leader (ID 4) because they had the highest `net_worth` amongst any other member in the group, and this group didn't already have someone appointed as leader.

**DBFiddle:** [db-fiddle.com/f/rH3TSBHBoNa9hthDKpBqEg/2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rH3TSBHBoNa9hthDKpBqEg/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update rows if they are the highest `net_worth` *(so there is no other row with a higher net worth)* for the group and if the group does not already have a leader.

This translates easily into two left joins that must find no records:

```sql
UPDATE `people` p1
LEFT JOIN `people` p2 on p2.group_id = p1.group_id AND (p2.net_worth,p2.id) > (p1.net_worth,p1.id)
LEFT JOIN `people` p3 on p3.group_id = p1.group_id AND p3.is_leader
SET p1.is_leader = 1
WHERE p2.id IS NULL AND p3.id IS NULL;
```

Here I chose to break ties on `net_worth` by which `id` is higher.  To set is_leader on the lowest tied `id` instead, do:

```
and (p2.net_worth > p1.net_worth or p2.net_worth=p1.net_worth and p2.id < p1.id)
```

To check some additional tie-breaking field before id, using or begins to get cumbersome so I prefer:

```
and coalesce(
    if(p2.net_worth=p1.net_worth,null,p2.net_worth > p1.net_worth),
    if(p2.tiebreaker=p1.tiebreaker,null,p2.tiebreaker > p1.tiebreaker),
    p2.id < p1.id  -- or change < to >
)
```

Comment: Another great solution, however would this still work if the `id` field was not in incrementing order?

Comment: not sure what you mean.  if there may be ties in net worth, you either need to set is_leader on them all (which both other answers do currently, I believe) or use some other criterion to decide; I chose to set it on the higher id, but it could use lower id or some other field instead or in addition to id: the on condition just needs to identify a p2 that is "higher" than p1, however you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using an update join:

```sql
UPDATE people p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT group_id, MAX(net_worth) AS max_net_worth,
           SUM(is_leader) AS leader_cnt
    FROM people
    GROUP BY group_id
) p2
    ON p2.group_id = p1.group_id AND
       p2.max_net_worth = p1.net_worth
SET
    is_leader = 1
WHERE
    p2.leader_cnt = 0;
```

Comment: this only works if, when is_leader is already set, it is on the highest net_worth of the group, something that is implied but not clearly specified in the question

Comment: As specified within the question, the update should not affect groups that already have an appointed leader.

Comment: Check the updated answer, the requirement was not 100% clear to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This query actually seems to set every person as a leader if the `net_worth` values are the same for two or more people that have the highest value, whereas it should only set the first eligible row found? DBFiddle with [example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rH3TSBHBoNa9hthDKpBqEg/5). I have tried added a `LIMIT` to the joined result in order to counter this but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In the UPDATE statement you can join the table to a query that returns the max `net_worth` and max `is_leader` of each `group_id`.
The max `net_worth` value will be used to determine which one will be the leader and the max `is_leader` value will be used to filter out the `group_id`s that already have a leader:

```
UPDATE people p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT group_id, MAX(net_worth) net_worth, MAX(is_leader) is_leader
  FROM people
  GROUP BY group_id
) t ON t.group_id = p.group_id AND t.net_worth = p.net_worth AND t.is_leader = 0
SET p.is_leader = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5c8a2e0f89a831c3b07449b9e24765d).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your answer was wrong when I started answering this question. You edited later to correct it.